# Is $\langle1,x\rangle$ a principal ideal of $Z[x]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I need to prove that $\langle n,x \rangle$ is principal ideal in $Z[x]$ if $n=0, 1, -1$.

Now my explanation is:
If $n=1$, then, clearly, $1\in\langle1,x\rangle$ and so $\langle 1,x \rangle=\mathbb{Z}[x]=\langle1\rangle$ , So $\langle 1,x \rangle$ is principal ideal.
Similar arguments hold for $n=-1$, And for $n=0$, clearly, $\langle x\rangle$ is a principal ideal.

Is my explanation correct? Can anyone kindly verify my answer? It's really very urgent !!!

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Can't express what a relief it is.